# Ensuring separate set of Puppet manifests for different VM name.

Tags: puppet

I have a module with multiple manifests. I have two types of VMs (for different functionality with "APP" and "PRT" as substring in their names). I have few manifests common for both the VMs but some manifests are specific to the VMs.

```
$hostname = generate('hostname').
```

I have the hostname.

All I need to implement is:

```
if(hostname matches regex(APP)){
    execute manifest a.pp & b.pp
}
else if (hostname matches regex(PRT)){
    execute manifest a.pp & bc.pp
}
```

How can I do this with puppet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `site.pp` (main manifest):

```
node /.*APP.*/ {
  class { 'a': }
  class { 'b': }
}
node /.*PRT.*/ {
  class { 'a': }
  class { 'bc': }
}
```

If your puppet codebase becomes more sophisticated then you can do more sophisticated class inclusion here, but this gets the job done for the case you are working with.

Note relevant documentation here: https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_node_definitions.html

Comment: Will this work with all the servers having APP and PRT?
I wont have to define for each server separately right?

Comment: Yes, it will work with them. You can modify the regexps as necessary for your needs.